# Lotus domino 8.5.3 xpage, no drop-down date options for Date Time Picker in IE11

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I drag and drop a Date Time Picker to XPage("aa").
![enter image description here][1]

but when I preview in IE11, and click the Date Time Picker, there is no drop-down date options. Why?
![enter image description here][2]

**The domino server is 8.5.3 without Extension library.**

Comment: You need to add `[1]: http://url.to/your/image.png` to the bottom of your post (same for `[2]`)

Comment: I couldn't add images, this website message:you need at least 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: You have enough reputation points to add pictures now :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work. I tested it with this simple XPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:inputText
        id="inputText1"
        value="#{sessionScope.dateTimeTest}">
        <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper1"></xp:dateTimeHelper>
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertDateTime type="both"></xp:convertDateTime>
        </xp:this.converter>
    </xp:inputText>
</xp:view>
```

on a Server 8.5.3 without ExtLib in IE11 and the picker worked as expected

[image]

I tested it with

- application theme "Server default" and "OneUI"
- option "Use runtime optimized JavaScript and CSS resources" set and not set
- IE11 with compatibility mode and without

Domino server 8.5.3 uses Dojo 1.6.1 by default.

**Press F12 in IE11 and have a look at developer tool's Console tab if there are error messages.** This might help you to find the cause of your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help! but I don't find "OneUI" in application theme, only "Server default" option.

Comment: You can't choose the theme by default. You have to write it. You can see a list of available themes in directory ...\data\domino\html\oneui...

Comment: The ability to choose themes (and add new themes for selection) was added in a later release

Comment: @KnutHerrmann Thanks for your help! I have solved this problem.

Answer (score 3):

IE11 support was added in Domino 9.0.1 FP2 http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2014/08/xpages-and-domino-9-0-1-fp2-upgrades-to-ckeditor-and-dojo.html

Check using developer tools for a Dojo error. In my experience, Internet Explorer is very draconian in supporting older versions of Dojo.

Comment: So how could I solve this problem? The boss doesn't agree to upgrade the Domino Server. User doesn't agree to degrade IE browser.

Comment: If your boss doesn't agree to upgrade the Domino server (which they should, if nothing else from a security perspective, such as the TLS upgrades and POODLE fixes, etc), then they should have no problem telling their users not to use IE 11. ;-)

Comment: Boss asked me to find a way to solve this problem, if I install XPage Extension library, this problem will or not be solved?

Comment: First step is to confirm it is a Dojo issue. If so, forcing compatibility mode may work, though I have never tested this. The fundamental issue is that in order to support applications used on the latest browsers, you need to be willing to keep platforms up-to-date, because you cannot guarantee that the browsers will be backwardly-compatible in the way something like the Notes Client has. And this is not just an Internet Explorer restriction, as the issues with iOS 8 last year showed.

Comment: The solution is easy: run setup.exe for 901

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a datetimehelper dojotype="dijit.form.DateTextBox" this might help